# flutter female and male toggle https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0u3t.png

Tags: flutter

1. I am not able to toggle container between container
2. How to fetch value from toggled or selected container

[image]

```
Container buildContainerGenderSelect({String gender,Color background,Color textColor}) {
  return Container( 
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    decoration: BoxDecoration( 
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(75.0),
      color: background),
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        gender,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: textColor, 
          fontSize: 25.0
        ),
      )
    ),
  );


Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    GestureDetector(
      child: buildContainerGenderSelect(
        gender: 'M',
        textColor:Colors.white,
        background: Colors.deepPurple
      ),
      onTap: () { 
        setState(() {
          buildContainerGenderSelect(
            gender: 'M',
            textColor: Colors.black,
            background: Colors.white
          );
        });
      },
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      child: buildContainerGenderSelect(
        gender: 'F',
        textColor: Colors.black,
        background: Colors.white
      ),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          buildContainerGenderSelect(
            gender: 'M',
            textColor: Colors.black,
            background: Colors.white
          );
        });
      },
    ),
  ]
)
```

Comment: Try to format your Code with - `dartfmt` - Dartfmt is included in the Dart SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `setState` incorrectly. You need to store the state there, not the widget.  And then use this state in building methods.

Example:

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {
  var _isMale = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: content(),
    );
  }

  Container _buildSelect({String text, Color background, Color textColor}) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(75.0), color: background),
      child: Center(
          child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(color: textColor, fontSize: 25.0),
      )),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildGenderSelect({String gender, bool selected}) {
    var button = selected
        ? _buildSelect(
            text: gender, textColor: Colors.black, background: Colors.white)
        : _buildSelect(
            text: gender, textColor: Colors.black, background: Colors.purple);

    return GestureDetector(
      child: button,
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _isMale = !_isMale;
        });
      },
    );
  }

  Widget content() {
    return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
        _buildGenderSelect(gender: "M", selected: _isMale),
        _buildGenderSelect(gender: "F", selected: !_isMale),
    ]);
  }
}
```

[image]